# How do I reset my manor so I can rebuild it with different options?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I currently have Windstad Manor and built it all. Now I regret some choices and I'd like to rethink and rebuild it.

Is there any console way to "nuke" the manor and rebuild it from ground up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but a bit of a  brainteaser to get it done.

Using the console you can type:

```
sqv byohhousepale
sqv byohhousefalkreath
sqv byohhousehjaalmarch
```

This will show all "enable" & "disable" ID's of variables for specific rooms and room-items in groups.

Then "just" with command `prid` "specific ID for room or item" select it remotely and  use command "disable" or "enable" to finish the operation.

BTW: go rather back in time in your save games or disable the DLC. I just want to point it out that it is possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What are we looking for if we want to remove an addition to the house? I added the enchanting tower, but then I realized it kinda sucks and I can't have kids.

Comment: FYI, you can still have kids without the 'bedroom' add-on.  Just need to put a dresser and beds upstairs.

Comment: But then how do you make new additions available in the drafting table outside?

Answer (score 18):

The only known way to reset the house is to disable the DLC, load the game, save it, then reenable the DLC.

There's no known way to reset or rebuild the house with different additions.

Just remember to take out everything inside that you want to keep.

Comment: Also note that you'll probably lose any building supplies (logs, clay, hinges, locks, etc.) that are part of the DLC.  Have fun gathering/making all *that* again.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I construct a house with the Hearthfire DLC, I'll save before hand to make sure I like the items I've added inside of the house because there isn't a way of undoing the changes once they've been committed. You'll have to reload a previous save and make sure you save before each incremental change to the house.

Answer (score -3):

It's easy... I am thinking that you didn't want some rooms, you wanted others? If that's the case, I'm pretty sure that you can just go back out to the drafting table and change the rooms... CAUTION! Everything in the room will be deleted!

Comment: nope, you can't change the rooms once you build them.

Comment: Where's the source!