# How to remove/reset a wing of my house without losing my wife?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I recently started playing Skyrim again and I am using my save from years ago. Back then my foolish self decided to build some wings on the Falkreath house, Lakeside manor.

From reading other forums I understand I can disable Hearthfire to reset my build. I did this but my concern is that my wife Ysolda also vanished from my Solitude home when I did this.

I used console commands to place and try to marry her again but it didn't work. Is there a way to restart without losing Ysolda?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset my manor so I can rebuild it with different options?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103728/how-do-i-reset-my-manor-so-i-can-rebuild-it-with-different-options)

Comment: It may be a duplicate but none of the others I saw mentioned a missing wife

Comment: Can you try asking her to move back to her house before disabling Hearthfire? Hearthfire modifies the vanilla houses to include a child's bedroom so it's possible this link was also connected to your spouse.

Comment: I do have the chat option to move to her house, I believe its cause of the kids. She is to tangled up in the Hearthfire DLC.

Comment: do NOT have the chat option*

Comment: @ZarthekTheCruel Can you move the kids, then Ysolda?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Namely with the (excessive) use of the console. I didn't check whether disabling and re-enabling the DLC removes your wife, but I very much assume so, so you will probably want this approach:

First you need to type

```
sqv byohhousefalkreath
```

This should show a lot of variables with IDs and 'enabled'/'disabled'. Those belong to specific rooms and items.

You can then use the command

```
prid <ID>
enable|disable
```

depending on whether you want to enable or disable it.

It can be very exhausting to search through the text-dump for the variable you want, but I wouldn't be aware of a proper list, so this will have to do.

In case you are interested: the command `prid` selects the specified ID and lets you issue commands especially for that ID.

Comment: It is indeed excessive, I wouldn't even know where to begin. Though it is viable I don't think ill be using it, thanks for the help.